# Get Milliseconds of specific date and time

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, utc

I want to get the milliseconds of the market open time(09:30 am cst)

```
  //date
  const date = new Date();
  const ddd = moment().format('ddd');
  const d = moment().format('D');
  const mmm = moment().format('MMM');
  const yyyy = moment().format('yyyy');

 

  const openMills = moment("2021-03-01 14:30:00GMT").format('x');

  console.log(openMills);
```

The error:

**Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format.**

Comment: Did you try using one of the formats the warning asked you to use, such as ISO8601?

Comment: Try removing `GMT` from the date? `2021-03-01 14:30:00`?

Comment: Why are there 8 lines of code when only one of them causes the warning? -> [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
export class DateTimeHelper {
  static getMills = (type) => {
    //date
    const date = new Date();
    const ddd = moment().format('ddd');
    const dd = moment().format('DD');
    const mm = moment().format('MM');
    const yyyy = moment().format('yyyy');
  
  
   const utcDate = new Date(yyyy +'-' +mm+'-'+dd+' 14:30:00');
   const utcDateClose = new Date(yyyy +'-' +mm+'-'+dd+' 21:00:00');
  
   const myOpenDate: any = new Date(Date.UTC(
      utcDate.getFullYear(),
      utcDate.getMonth(),
      utcDate.getDate(),
      utcDate.getHours(),
      utcDate.getMinutes()
   ));
  
   const myCloseDate: any = new Date(Date.UTC(
    utcDateClose.getFullYear(),
    utcDateClose.getMonth(),
    utcDateClose.getDate(),
    utcDateClose.getHours(),
    utcDateClose.getMinutes()
  ));
   
   const openTimeInMills = Date.parse(myOpenDate);
   const closeTimeInMills = Date.parse(myCloseDate);
  
   console.log(openTimeInMills);
   console.log(closeTimeInMills);

   if(type === 'open'){
    return openTimeInMills;
   }

   if(type === 'close'){
    return closeTimeInMills;
   }
 

  }
}
```

Comment: Code–only answers aren't that helpful. A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your answer fixes it.